Quit tail -f command from script
I am doing tail -f -n 10 test.log .
I want this tail command to terminate once a signal file is created at some location .
say finish.txt. If finish.txt file exists then stop tailing or else continue

tail does not have such a behaviour. You could run tail in the background, get the PID, create a loop that checks the file and kills that PID.

via inotify interface it's something like DIR=/tmp/nottoobig FIL=finish.txt KIL=12345; mkdir -p "$DIR" && inotifywait -e create "$DIR" --include "^$DIR/$FIL\$" && kill "$KIL" (replace DIRFILKIL with your data). There could be other options depending on task's specific requirements.

That should take care of the problem:
signal_file=some/location/finish.txt

tail -f -n 10 test.log &

until [ -e "$signal_file" ]; do sleep 1; done

kill %

